# displaying the name of the user logged in by clicking the button

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've made this IT Support Ticketing System where employees could send their issues with the system.

So here's what the administrators see.

[image: IT Support Ticketing System]

Basically what I want to happen is when I click accept the full name of the user(administrator) logged in will be displayed below assignee.

So far this is what I've done:

I have a session code on top of my form:

```js
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

//Include the database connection file
include "database_connection.php"; 

//Check to be sure that a valid session has been created
if(isset($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]))
{
 
 //Check the database table for the logged in user information
 $check_user_details = mysql_query("select * from `employee` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"])."'");
 //Validate created session
 if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_details) < 1)
 {
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  header("location: login.php");
 }
 else
 {
 
 //Get all the logged in user information from the database users table
 $get_user_details = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_details);
 
 $user_id = strip_tags($get_user_details['id']);
 $fullname = strip_tags($get_user_details['fullname']);
 $username = strip_tags($get_user_details['username']);
 $email = strip_tags($get_user_details['email']);
 $address = strip_tags($get_user_details['address']);
 $gender = strip_tags($get_user_details['gender']);
 $contact = strip_tags($get_user_details['contact']);
 $user_access_level = strip_tags($get_user_details['user_levels']);
 $passwd = strip_tags($get_user_details['password']);
 $picture = strip_tags($get_user_details['picture']);
 $sickleave = strip_tags($get_user_details['sickleave']);
 $vacationleave = strip_tags($get_user_details['vacationleave']);
?>
```

Here's what I did:

```js
<?php
     include ('database.php');
     $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM tickets order by ticketno DESC");
     $result ->execute();
     for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
    ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['time']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['priority']; ?></td>
      <td>
       <form method="post" action="update1.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticketno" value="<?php echo $row_message['ticketno']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $row_message['fullname'];?>" name="accept"></input>
       </form>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['subject']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_message['problem']; ?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
```

Update1.php:

```js
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['accept']))
    {
        $msg = "Approved";
        $assignee=$_POST['accept'];
    }

    $ticketno=$_POST['ticketno'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'companydb');

    $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET assignee = '$assignee' WHERE ticketno = '$ticketno'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=tickets.php?msg=$msg");
    else
        var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
 
?>
```

Here are my tables:

[image: Employee]

[image: tickets]

By the way I know that mysql is deprecated. I will definitely change it in the future, for now I need to figure this out.

Comment: **Warning** mysql_* functions are deprecated. See warning message : http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: @Syscall I know that. I will change it eventually. For now I just need to figure this out.

Comment: what you are trying to achive `when I click accept the full name of the user(administrator) logged in will be displayed below assignee.`?

Comment: @vel Basically the user who is logged in. For example John Doe is the user logged in. When John Doe clicks accept, the name John Doe should be displayed below the `assignee` column.

Comment: do you want to show reload or without reload?

Comment: @vel What do you mean by reload?

Comment: @vel I guess either way will do.

Comment: do you want to show after page reload or without reload?

Comment: @vel I guess when you click accept, the page would reload a little and then the name would show up

Comment: Does your database updated correctly, with the good value of `assignee`?

Comment: @Syscall Not sure if I know what you mean

Comment: When you click on the button, what happens on your database? Does the values are correct?

Comment: I've undeleted my anwser and updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to information stored in your `tickets` table. So you could just use an if-statement to display the assignee name instead of form.

```
<?php
include ('database.php');
$result = $database->prepare ("SELECT * FROM tickets order by ticketno DESC");
$result ->execute();
for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['time']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['priority']; ?></td>
    <?php if ($row_message['assignee']) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['assignee']; ?></td>
    <?php else : ?>
        <td><form method="post" action="update1.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="ticketno" value="<?php echo $row_message['ticketno']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="accept"></input>
        </form></td>
    <?php endif ; ?>

    <td><?php echo $row_message['subject']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_message['problem']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php   }   ?>
```

And I think you're storing not the value you want in the database:

```
$check_user_details = mysql_query("select * from `employee` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"])."'");
//Validate created session
if(mysql_num_rows($check_user_details) < 1)
{
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

//Get all the logged in user information from the database users table
$get_user_details = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_details);

if(isset($_POST['accept']))
{
    $msg = "Approved";
    //$assignee=$_POST['accept'];
    $assignee = $get_user_details['fullname'];
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but for some reason I'm getting the `undefined variable: get_user_details`.

Comment: @JohnY I've updated the anwser. You have to get information another time.

Comment: @JohnY You maybe should also `session_start()` at the begining. But, I think you should store the user ID instead of user name. Then use a `LEFT JOIN` on your `ticket` query to get the name.

Comment: @JohnY Yes, I've made a copy of your `check_user_details` to get the user informations.

Comment: @JohnY Glad that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    include ('database.php');

    $result = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM tickets order by ticketno DESC");
    $result ->execute();
    for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['full_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['time']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['priority']; ?></td>
        <?php if(empty($row_message['full_name'])) {?>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="update1.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="ticketno" value="<?php echo $row_message['ticketno']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $row_message['full_name'];?>" name="accept"></input>
            </form>
        </td>
        <?php }else { ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row_message['full_name'];?>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['subject']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_message['problem']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   }   ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting the underfined index fullname.

Comment: I got the answer, thanks for the help tho :) I've upvoted your answer tho